# How can showing text in a post only for the author

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress , I want when the author of the post reading his post showing text like' Delete Post , Edit Post , .... etc" only for the author not for all users.

First: I want to know the id of user login 
Second: I want to know the id of author ..
Then:

```
if($user_id_login == $id_author){
echo 'Delete Post , Edit Post ... etc';
}
```

but from where do I get the `$user_id_login` and `$id_author` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if( $current_user->ID == $post->post_author ){
        echo "<a href='#'>edit</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: oh , I'm sorry , I don't know about this before .. thank you very much .. I accept your answer ^_^ ..